# Why can't we build a styrofoam 747?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, material-science

What properties of materials explain why building the same structure at different scales requires materials of different densities and strengths?

Consider an airliner, and flying models thereof at various sizes.  A 1-ounce model is made of thin foam and plastic film: steel and aluminum, even similarly thin, would be too heavy.  A 5-pound model's ribs and spars might need balsa or spruce.  A 100- or 1000-pounder abandons foam for wood or metal or composites.  Over 100,000 pounds, even wood is abandoned.

This isn't about flight per se.  The same progression is seen in model vehicles (nobody uses a steel tube chassis under 10 pounds), foamboard architectural models, and so on.

Comment: Think about the volume vs. surface area relationships, as well as material density and strength-per-weight for each material. Do you see (or think there may be) a trend between small and large scale models and the properties of the materials chosen?

Comment: Galileo answered this question in "Discourses and Mathematical Demonstrations Relating to Two New Sciences": https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two_New_Sciences. It's a fascinating read, even 378 years after its publication.

Comment: If one of you posts this as an answer, I'll accept it:  The https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square-cube_law says that enlarging a structure n times (linearly) enlarges mass by n cubed, but cross-section of spars, ribs, bones by only n squared.  So these members need materials that are stronger in compression. The same reasoning applies to tensile members (skins).

Answer (score 0):

This is the whole question addressed by adimensional transforms in physics, in order to make reductions models that still share the same physics - when it's possible. For instance if you want to reduce a set up of ocean and shore, you also have to change the viscosity and density of fluids and solids used, and the time scale.

But in many case this is not even possible, for instance if both surface and volume forces occurs, typically for a car engine. And if you can't change materials - typically for bones in nature - then you have to change other parameters - e.g. section - to conserve the right thing, ending at something looking very different... or yielding new impossibilities to be turnaround again.

Comment: Is there a standard English term for "adimensional transforms"?  Google only led me into the weeds.